# How to identify if the batch script if suddenly close or not?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to ask on how to do the code on batch script like this

```
IF(Batch script file suddenly close)
ECHO SCRIPT FAIL>>LOG.txt
ELSE (
ECHO DO PROCESS LIKE ALWAYS
```

i want to detect it because i need to save in every log file if any error occur during the process of XCOPY copy/paste.

Comment: You... want the script to keep running if it suddenly closes? What?

Comment: i mean if suddenly the script is closed it will record in log.txt for error occur

Comment: How can a script know if it closes unexpectedly? The script isn't running anymore, so it has no way of doing anything. It's like how dead people don't know they're dead.

Comment: So basically to overcome this problem once the script run again, there will be a process where need to identify if the last script have file copied or not?

Comment: Instead of trying to detect whether your script closes unexpectedly, I would debug the script and try to avoid unexpected closure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you have a batch file call the batch file to be run? This will not take care of the situation of the currently executing shell getting killed or erroring out in some way.

If this is not adequate, you will probably need to have the script check for the existence of a file that is written by a successful completion. If the success file does not exist, then cleanup as needed.

**1.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

CALL 2.bat
SET "EXITCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%"
IF %EXITCODE% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO ERROR: Script 2.bat failed, ERRORLEVEL = %EXITCODE%
) ELSE (
    ECHO NB: Back from 2.bat, process normally
)
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

**2.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO NB: Starting 2
ping -n 10 localhost
ECHO NB: in 2 ERRORLEVEL is %ERRORLEVEL%
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```